# Death Mask Duplicant Imprint of Platinum Angel

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Does the imprint ability of [Death-Mask Duplicant](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDeath-Mask%20Duplicant%5d) allow me to copy the ability of the [Platinum Angel](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=48580) in the graveyard not the flying , the one where I cannot lose?

Answer (score 8):

No. Death-Mask Duplicant only allows you to copy the effects that are explicitly listed on it - flying, fear, first strike, double strike, haste, trample, and all forms of landwalk and protection. Exiling Platinum Angel would only give the duplicant flying.

Comment: Can you provide the rulings that support your answer?

Comment: I'm not sure there are any relevant rulings here; it's simply the actual text on the card.

Answer (score 2):

No, Death-Mask Duplicant does not copy any abilities.

It has an ability that can grant it other abilities, and those other abilities are listed in the text: Flying, fear, first strike, double strike, haste, landwalk, protection, and trample. The abilities of the imprinted card are not copied or given to Death-Mask Duplicant. Rather Death-Mask Duplicant conditionally has the listed abilities.